# Ошибка при создании вычисляемого поля

Tags: ms-access

Не получается создать вычисляемое поле через построитель выражений.

`IIf( [Цвет травы] = "Зеленый"; "Верно"; "Не верно")`

Сначала пытается что-то вычислить, но в итоге выдает ошибку

> Проверьте, что выражение IIf( [Цвет травы] = "Зеленый"; "Верно"; "Не
>   верно") включает поля, которые существуют в данной таблице

Но столбец я выбираю двойным щелчком из списка, так что неправильно указать его я не могу.

Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: А где именно строите выражение? Форма, запрос, отчет? И на каком этапе выскакивает ошибка?

Comment: Есть самая обычная таблица в базе данных, я пытаюсь добавить столбец в конец этой таблицы. В качестве типа выбираю "Вычисляемый" и открывается редактор. Вот в нем и пытаюсь создать

Comment: Настоятельно не рекомендую использовать вычисляемые поля в таблицах в виду их глючности. Все дальнейшие вычисления делайте в запросах, в таблицах храните только исходные данные.

Comment: Проверил у себя - работает, все видит. У меня только в качестве разделителя запятая, а не точка с запятой, но у меня локаль не русская.

Comment: Русская локаль требует именно точку с запятой. Я пробовал запятую, но сразу же получал сообщение об ошибке синтаксиса.